# Java Compatibility -- GraphDB Free Edition -- Standalone Variant

Tags: graphdb

When starting the standalone version via graphdb.cmd the following message is given:
"This GraphDB distribution requires Java 8, 11 or 12 but you have Java 15".
However, the startup is successsful and GraphDB WorkBench can be started.
Do I have to expect some "hidden" problems in the future use, when I keep running the system based on (Open)Java 15?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking you should have no problems using Java 15, but this mean that GraphDB was not tested with this version and it's hard to say if there could be potential problems.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Then I will try.